# Gradle invoking different tasks for each subproject

Tags: java, android, gradle, spring-boot

I have the following set up:

Project

- spring boot app
- java classes that are packaged into a jar
- android project

  - app module of the android project

I am trying to set up gradle build so that i get runnable spring boot jar application, java jar library that is installed in the local maven repo and an apk file for the android.

- To get an apk file I need to run assembleDebug task
- To publish java ibrary I need to run publish task
- To get spring executable I need to run compileJave task

Question is what task to run on the top level root gradel.build file to get different tasks accomplished?

root gradle:

```
allprojects {
    task hello << { task -> println "I'm $task.project.name" }
}
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Spring Boot gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'

buildscript {
    ext {
            springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-            plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.5')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Java Proj gradle:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'commonobjects'
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Android Proj gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
```

Android App gradle:

```
def ANDROID_SUPPORT_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '25.1.0'
def DAGGER_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '2.8'
def OK_HTTP_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '3.5.0'
def RETROFIT_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '2.1.0'
def RETROFIT_JACKSON_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '2.1.0'
def BUTTER_KNIFE_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '8.5.1'
def JAVAX_ANNOTATION_JSR250_API_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '1.0'
def GREEN_ROBOT_EVENT_BUS_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '3.0.0'
def RX_JAVA_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '2.0.5'
def RX_ANDROID_JAVA_DEPENDENCY_VERSION = '2.0.1'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'assembleDebug'

buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.9"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'idea'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

//        debug {
//            buildConfigField "String", "PARSE_APPLICATION_ID", "\"1\""
//            buildConfigField "String", "PARSE_API_KEY", "\"1\""
//        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles "android-proguard-android.txt", "proguard-rules.txt"

            // buildConfigField "String", "PARSE_APPLICATION_ID", "\"1\""
            // buildConfigField "String", "PARSE_API_KEY", "\"1\""
        }
   }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Add jars supplied
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Test related
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:0.5"

    // Android support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"

    // An HTTP & HTTP/2 client for Android and Java applications
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${OK_HTTP_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"

    // Retrofit: A type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${RETROFIT_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:${RETROFIT_JACKSON_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"

    // Butterknife: Field and method binding for Android views
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${BUTTER_KNIFE_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${BUTTER_KNIFE_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"

    // Dagger DI
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${DAGGER_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${DAGGER_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    provided "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:${JAVAX_ANNOTATION_JSR250_API_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"

    // Event bus
    compile "org.greenrobot:eventbus:${GREEN_ROBOT_EVENT_BUS_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"

    // RxJava a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences.
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${RX_JAVA_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${RX_ANDROID_JAVA_DEPENDENCY_VERSION}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create your task that will depend on three different tasks. It's possible to have dependencies across subprojects as well:

```
task myAllTask {
}

myAllTask.dependsOn assembleDebug, publish, compileJava
```

For running tasks from subprojects:

```
myAllTask.dependsOn ':bootProj:assembleDebug', ':javaProj:publish', ':androidProj:compileJava
```

Comment: So I can just run gradle myAllTask in root folder. And build.gradle will containg exactly what code? And another thing is that the order also matters, i have to publish javaProj first, since it is a dependency for both server and android app. @sm4

Comment: Maybe try to be more specific in your question. Draft how your gradle files are organized. Root gradle would contain the task {} and then the dependsOn. You should also have a dependency on the subproject that needs to run first in the dependencies block.

Comment: I have added my current sources, my question is indeed wage since i might be doing multiple things wrong in gradle. But the aim is to generate all artifacts from all modules and then further use them to upload, deploy etc. I don't also quite understand why android project has to be wrapped into android module instead of just having app as main android module. @sm4